# UIRouter Url redirection in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I was working on some specific task in an `angular2` project, my issue resides in the routing part. I've imported

```
import { UIRouter } from 'ui-router-ng2';
```

instead of :

```
import { Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

so i could not recognize how the redirection should be, because in the ordinary case when instantiating a `router` in the `constructor` will be :

```
this.router.navigate(['/Blablabla']);
```

However, now I cannot find an alternative method to `navigate` within the `UIRouter` so I can redirect to a specific component. 
Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router (`ui-router-ng2`) is different from the Angular 2 Router (`@angular/router`).

#### programmatic:

In ui-router-ng2, you can navigate programmatically by injecting `router: UIRouter` and calling [the go method](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go): `router.stateService.go('somestate')`.

Alternatively you can inject the state service directly as `$state: StateService` and call `$state.go('somestate')`

#### redirects:

You can also create a state and use the [`redirectTo` property](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto) to redirect elsewhere:

```
var redirectFromState = {
  name: 'landingPage1',
  url: '/landingpage/for-search-engine-or-whatever`
  redirectTo: 'login'
}

var loginState = {
  name: 'login',
  url: '/login',
  component: Login
}
```

#### hooks:

You can register a [transition hook](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onstart) to redirect based on some criteria.

```
router.transitionService.onStart({ to: 'auth.**' }, transition => {
  if (!transition.injector().get(AuthService).isAuthenticated()) {
    return router.stateService.target('login');
  }
}
```